# set password as a variable while typing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Trying to avoid any browser's stuff about `autocomplete`, `password suggestion` etc.

And at the same time keep the `show/hide letters` functionality.

The idea is to keep `password` as a variable, regardless of `show/hide` state.

In the code below problem is if user press `Backspace` or `Delete` key. In that case the whole concept crushes down.

Any help?

```js
var pass = "";

$('#inpass').on('input', function(){
 if(!$('#checka').is(':checked')){
  let a = $(this).val();
  let b = a.substr(-1);
  pass += b;
  let c = a.replace(/.$/, '*');
  $(this).val(c);
  console.log(pass);
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type='text' id='inpass' maxlength='25' placeholder='password' title='password' autocomplete='off'>
<br><br>
<input type='checkbox' id='checka'>
<label for='checka' id='labela'>show letters</label>
```

Comment: Why don't you just prevent pasting?

Comment: The whole concept also fails if the user uses arrow keys to change a previous character, not just the last one.

Comment: Ref. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530/how-do-you-disable-browser-autocomplete-on-web-form-field-input-tag

Comment: @Taplar, you're right about the arrow key. And you link - it is asked (and answered) in 2008, accepted answer edited in 2015.

Comment: didn't get your point why don't you just use **type="password"**

Comment: Are you suggesting that because of the age of the answers they are no longer relevant?

Comment: @Taplar, of course, that's 11/4 years ago.

Comment: So you've tried the answers and seen that they no longer work?

Comment: Why don't you just toggle between the two fields?

Comment: Not at all clear what higher level problem you are really trying to solve here. Seems like a science experiment gone bad. Once you change the value what about when it needs to be submitted?

Comment: @Taplar, in fact, I see now, I tried that solution, and didn't work. At least in Chrome

Comment: @SameerAhmad epascarello he's using text to avoid the auto fill I assume.

Comment: @puerto there are multiple solutions on that page.  one including to randomize the password field name.  did you try that solution?

Comment: @SameerAhmad, as Taplar said - to avoid `autofill` AND `password suggestion` from the browser's side.

Comment: You might could also potentially leave the name off of the field until you submit, and add the name to it before the submit goes through.  If the autofill relies on it being a password field with a name, that could also potentially bypass the autofill.  But that's speculation that would need to be tested.

Comment: @Taplar, thanks, but I need a real solution.

Comment: If it works, it is a real solution.  As your question currently stands it is too broad.  As have been mentioned in the comments, there are multiple issues with your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Added  checks if it is delete or add

```js
var pass = "";
String.prototype.replaceAt = function (index, replacement) {
    return this.substr(0, index) + replacement + this.substr(index + replacement.length);
}

function setCaretPosition(ctrl, pos) {
    if (ctrl.setSelectionRange) {
        ctrl.focus();
        ctrl.setSelectionRange(pos, pos);
    } else if (ctrl.createTextRange) {
        var range = ctrl.createTextRange();
        range.collapse(true);
        range.moveEnd('character', pos);
        range.moveStart('character', pos);
        range.select();
    }
}

$('#inpass').on('input', function(){
 var el = document.getElementById('inpass');
    let caretStart = el.selectionStart;

    let a = $(this).val();
    var deleteLength = pass.length - a.length;
    var addLength = deleteLength * -1;
    let b = a.substr(caretStart - addLength, addLength);
    if (deleteLength > 0) {
        pass = pass.substr(0, caretStart) + pass.substr(caretStart + deleteLength, pass.length - 1);
    } else {
        if (caretStart < a.length) {
            pass = pass.substr(0, caretStart - addLength) + b + pass.substr(caretStart - addLength);
        } else {
            pass += b;
        }
    }
    if (!$('#checka').is(':checked')) {
        if (a != "" && addLength > 0) {
            let c = a.replaceAt(caretStart - addLength, '*'.repeat(addLength));
            $(this).val(c);
        }

    }
    setCaretPosition(el, caretStart);
    console.log(pass);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type='text' id='inpass' maxlength='25' placeholder='password' title='password' autocomplete='off'>
<br><br>
<input type='checkbox' id='checka'>
<label for='checka' id='labela'>show letters</label>
```

Comment: Does strange things when ticking the 'show letters' checkbox and when using cursor keys

Comment: @Amstel, almost perfectly, do you have any solution for the case in `freedomn's` notice?

Comment: @puerto I have updated the code to address freedom-m comments